# How to provide null values in TDEs in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, json, templates, marklogic

I'm creating a JavaScript template in JSON for my document. One of the fields is null. The nullable:true is not working on it.

I gave the  nullable as true so it accepts the value only when it is "" and not as null. The document insertion fails if I have the TDE in my schemas.

```
               {
                    "name": "description",
                    "scalarType": "string",
                    "val": "/envelope/description",
                    "nullable": true
                }
```

I want the document to be inserted and this particular field to be read as void that the nullable property is doing in "". 
What changes can I do for the same?

Answer (score 1):

I added this:

```
"invalidValues":"ignore"
```

This solved the issue.